# How do I create 5 buttons and assign individual click events dynamically?

Tags: c#, winforms, events, dynamic, button

I need to create 5 buttons dynamically on windows form and each button should respond to click event. I tried it but all buttons are responding to same event.

Comment: Show us what you have tried so far.

Comment: Buttons don't respond to events.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

This is what Nick is talking about are your two options (You should be able to run this code and see both options):

```
  public Form1()
  {
     InitializeComponent();

     for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
     {
        Button button = new Button();
        button.Location = new Point(20, 30 * i + 10);
        switch (i)
        {
           case 0:
              button.Click += new EventHandler(ButtonClick);
              break;
           case 1:
              button.Click += new EventHandler(ButtonClick2);
              break;
           //...
        }
        this.Controls.Add(button);
     }

     for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
     {
        Button button = new Button();
        button.Location = new Point(160, 30 * i + 10);
        button.Click += new EventHandler(ButtonClickOneEvent);
        button.Tag = i;
        this.Controls.Add(button);
     }
  }

  void ButtonClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
     // First Button Clicked
  }
  void ButtonClick2(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
     // Second Button Clicked
  }

  void ButtonClickOneEvent(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
     Button button = sender as Button;
     if (button != null)
     {
        // now you know the button that was clicked
        switch ((int)button.Tag)
        {
           case 0:
              // First Button Clicked
              break;
           case 1:
              // Second Button Clicked
              break;
           // ...
        }
     }
  }
```

Comment: will these buttons responds to click events, like when i click button1, message should display "Button 1 Clicked", on clicking button2 it should show "Button 2 Clicked." and so on...

Comment: They definitely will, go ahead and test it by putting in breakpoints or adding MessageBox.Show("Add my comments here"); to see it work.

Comment: `public void AddHandler(Control control, string eventName, Delegate handler)
        {
            control.GetType().GetEvent(eventName).AddEventHandler(control, handler);   }`

Comment: Good answer. Some general advice to newer WinForms developers for creating controls dynamically: (1) On your form in Design view, drop the control you want to create. Size and position the control where you need it. (2) Find its' name (say `button1`) and open the form `Designer.cs` file. (3) Locate the control of interest and copy/paste that code somewhere (e.g. Notepad). (4) Return to the design view and delete your temporary control. (5) Use the code you copy/pasted to write your dynamic creation code as @SwDevMan81 does here.

Answer (score 8):

I assume you're in a loop and do something like this?

```
Button newButton = new Button();
newButton.Click += new EventHandler(newButton_Clicked);
```

You're registering the same method for all buttons.  You'll need individual methods for each button.  Alternatively, you can assign each button a different identifying property and in your handler, check to see which button was the sender.

From there you can take appropriate action.

Answer (score 4):

Guessing what you might have tried: Yes, all buttons fire their events to the same method, but the `sender`-parameter of your callback method contains a reference to the button that actually caused the specific event.

Answer (score -1):

```
button b =new button ();
b.text = " enter text";
b.click =+(then press Tab using key board)
```

Comment: And how it solve the problem?