# How to set same button events for ListBox (value) index or treeview nodes?

Tags: c#, arrays, treeview, simulation, listboxitem

I have C# Win-form as shown below. I also have few array as a menu for List-box.

```
public string[] ArrayMain = {"1.Water","2.Air","3.Soil","4.Fire"};
public string[] ArrayWater = {"1.Salty","2.Fresh", "3.Contaminated"};
public string[] ArraySalty = {"1.AA", "2.BB", "3.CC"};
public string[] ArrayFresh = {"1.DD", "2.EE", "3.FF"};
public string[] ArrayContaminated = {"1.XX", "2.YY", "3.ZZ"} ;
public string[] ArrayAir = {"1.Fresh", "2.Contaminated"};
public string[] ArraySoil = {"1.Normal", "2.Contaminated"};
public string[] ArrayFire = {"1.Low","2.Mid","3.High"};
```

When the application start in the Main List-box loaded with first array values.

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    ListBoxMain.Items.AddRange(ArrayMain);
    listView1.Items.Add(ArrayMain[0])
    // User choose: 1.Water
}
```

If user press button 1 then application clears the Main List-box and loads with that selection. This time List-box loaded with;

```
ListBoxMain.Items.AddRange(ArrayWater);
listView1.Items.Add(ArrayMain[0])
// User choose: 1.Salty
```

Now if the user press button 2 then application clears the Main List-box and the Selected Menus List-Box will have values like;

> ***1.Water
>   1.Salty
>   2.BB***

Then application will get the first letter (number) as fixed with format like;

> ***112***

and send it to WFC service. WFC services will know what to do with "112". My major problem is that I have to set all my button for List-box index (or combo-box as I say). Example if user press button 1 first time then user have to select that menus array into List-box. And again if user press button 1 then button 1 have to be connected List-box index (new values).

In my previous question for this  interesting problem user @Eugene suggested to me that I can turn the logic into tree-view. And he stated as;

> ***where nodes contain Items for combo-box (key-string to show, value - value to use later). When you push buttons you will add respective node item into some queue and load new items. In leaf nodes you will
>   contain Action> that will call respective service
>   method (for many options it can be the same action)***

I try to apply many logic and I spend nearly 10 days to make a simulator works as expected, but I failed. I realy like to have some information so I can set my **button 1** events to ListBox (index) or Treview (nodes). If someone point me, even how to set my button 1 events as I stated above then rest will be easy for me.

Kind Regards,

First Time the app start:

[image: App Start]

After the user press buttons:
[image: Pos Terminal Simulation]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you @Eugene. I made it. Here it is.

**For Main;**

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    TreeNode tNode;
    //MAIN NODE 1
    tNode = treeView1.Nodes.Add("1.Water");
    tNode = treeView1.Nodes.Add("2.Air");
    tNode = treeView1.Nodes.Add("3.Soil");
    tNode = treeView1.Nodes.Add("4.Fire");

    // WATER NODE
    treeView1.Nodes[0].Nodes.Add("1.Salty");
    treeView1.Nodes[0].Nodes.Add("2.Fresh");
    treeView1.Nodes[0].Nodes.Add("3.Contaminated");

    // AIR NODE
    treeView1.Nodes[1].Nodes.Add("1.Fresh");
    treeView1.Nodes[1].Nodes.Add("2.Contaminated");

    // SOIL NODE
    treeView1.Nodes[2].Nodes.Add("1.Normal");
    treeView1.Nodes[2].Nodes.Add("2.Contaminated");

    // FIRE NODE
    treeView1.Nodes[3].Nodes.Add("1.Low");
    treeView1.Nodes[3].Nodes.Add("2.Mid");
    treeView1.Nodes[3].Nodes.Add("3.High");

    // SALTY NODE
    treeView1.Nodes[0].Nodes[0].Nodes.Add("1.AA");
    treeView1.Nodes[0].Nodes[0].Nodes.Add("2.BB");
    treeView1.Nodes[0].Nodes[0].Nodes.Add("3.CC");

    // FRESH NODE
    treeView1.Nodes[0].Nodes[1].Nodes.Add("1.DD");
    treeView1.Nodes[0].Nodes[1].Nodes.Add("2.EE");
    treeView1.Nodes[0].Nodes[1].Nodes.Add("3.FF");

    // CONTAMINATED NODE
    treeView1.Nodes[0].Nodes[2].Nodes.Add("1.XX");
    treeView1.Nodes[0].Nodes[2].Nodes.Add("2.YY");
    treeView1.Nodes[0].Nodes[2].Nodes.Add("3.ZZ");


    //Clear ListBox items
    ListBoxMain.Items.Clear();

    //Load ListBox First time
    foreach (TreeNode n in treeView1.Nodes)
    {
        ListBoxMain.Items.Add(n.Text);
    }
}
```

**For Buttons:**

```
// BTN 1
private void Btn_1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int value = 1 - 1;
    int iCount = ListBoxMain.Items.Count;

    if (iCount > value)
    {
        string item = ListBoxMain.Items[value].ToString();
        TreviewNodesSelection(item, value);
    }
}

// BTN 2
private void Btn_2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int value = 2 - 1;
    int iCount = ListBoxMain.Items.Count;

    if (iCount > value)
    {
        string item = ListBoxMain.Items[value].ToString();
        TreviewNodesSelection(item, value);
    }
}
```

**Then created a TreviewNodesSelection:**

```
//TreviewNodesSelection
private void TreviewNodesSelection(string item, int value)
{
    textBox1.Text = item;
    listBoxMenu.Items.Add(item);


    //Find Nodes first
    Traverse(treeView1.Nodes, item);

    //Clear ListBox items
    ListBoxMain.Items.Clear();

    //Get a First ChildNode via Parenet Name
    if (treeView1.SelectedNode.Nodes.Count != 0)
    {
        foreach (TreeNode v in treeView1.SelectedNode.Nodes)
        {
            ListBoxMain.Items.Add(v.Text);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Now you can start calculation...");
    }
}
```

**And this is TreeView Node Selection**

```
private void Traverse(TreeNodeCollection nodes, string findtext)
{
    foreach (TreeNode node in nodes)
    {
        if (node.Text.ToString().Trim() == findtext)
        {
            node.TreeView.SelectedNode = node.NextNode;
            treeView1.SelectedNode = node;
            node.TreeView.Focus();
            //MessageBox.Show(node.Text + " is selected...");
        }
        Traverse(node.Nodes, findtext);
    }
}
```

I learn a lot from http://stackoverflow.com so this is my few cent contribution.

Kind Regards

[image: Pos Simulation]