# How to open Popup by clicking on grid view item in windows store app?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-store-apps

I want to open popup by clicking on button in gridView element, inside popup I have three options by clicking on that option I want to navigate to another page with the id of the element

[image]

i want to open popup on click on button inside the gridView element  my code looks like :-

```
<GridView x:Name="Test" Grid.Row="1" Margin="20,20,20,20" >
        <GridView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="250" Height="250">
                    <Button Background="Red" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="100" Content="OpenPopup" Click="Button_PointerPressed"></Button>                     
                    <Popup x:Name="Mypopup">
                        <TextBlock Text="hi"/>
                    </Popup>                    
                    <StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Background="{ThemeResource ListViewItemOverlayBackgroundThemeBrush}">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" Foreground="{ThemeResource ListViewItemOverlayForegroundThemeBrush}" Style="{StaticResource TitleTextBlockStyle}" Height="60" Margin="15,0,15,0"/>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Subtitle}" Foreground="{ThemeResource ListViewItemOverlaySecondaryForegroundThemeBrush}" Style="{StaticResource CaptionTextBlockStyle}" TextWrapping="NoWrap" Margin="15,0,15,10"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </GridView.ItemTemplate>
    </GridView>
```

on click event

```
 private void Button_PointerPressed(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        Mypopup.isopen = true;

    }
```

Error:-The name 'Mypopup' does not exist in the current context

I am a newbie.. so help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you have to do is on the `Onclick` event of your gridview's button do the following code :

```
popup.isopen = true
```

Then in your popup if you want to navigate to another page all you have to do is use `Navigate` on the proper event

```
Frame.Navigate(typeof(YourPage),YourID);
```

EDIT : If the buttons in your gridview are added through code and you want to do the event on those then make sure that they have different names such as : `GrdButton1`/`GrdButton2` and then give them [an event dynamicly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2104299/how-to-handle-programmatically-added-button-events-c-sharp)

If they are added in the `XAML` then simply add it an event there

```
<Button x:Name="ButtonTest"
        Click="ButtonTest_Click"/>
```

If none of this answers your question please add more details to it

Comment: thnx micbobo .I was using PointerPressed event . It was not working .... my friend told me not to use click event in windows store app .... which is best  plz guide me ...

Comment: Error:- The name 'Mypopup' does not exist in the current context......
. what to do???

Comment: @DineshTomer Did you get it figured out ?