# Create controls dynamically

Tags: c#, controls, dynamic

I want to know if this is possible in c# winform.

create control when ever button is pressed and place it at given location.

I think it is possible like this

```
private TextBox txtBox = new TextBox();
private Button btnAdd = new Button();
private ListBox lstBox = new ListBox();
private CheckBox chkBox = new CheckBox();
private Label lblCount = new Label();
```

but the problem lies when ever button is pressed same name controls are created.How to avoid that

What da........
i wrote and no exception i was expecting it because control already contains `btnAdd` instead as many button create as many you want.
Accessing them will be issue but it will be solved by `@drachenstern` method correct?

```
  private void button1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Button btnAdd = new Button();

            btnAdd.BackColor = Color.Gray;
            btnAdd.Text = "Add";
            btnAdd.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(90, 25+i);
            btnAdd.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(50, 25);
            this.Controls.Add(btnAdd);
            i = i + 10;
        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try the solution I posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1434282/how-do-i-create-5-buttons-and-assign-individual-click-events-dynamically/1434422#1434422).  It will dynamically create 5 buttons in the constructor.  Just move the code to the button click event and it should add the buttons dynamically and register with the `Click` events.

Answer (score 4):

```
int currentNamingNumber = 0;

txtBox.Name = "txtBox" + currentNamingNumber++;
```

Rinse, Repeat.

Gives each element a unique numeric name, allows you to find out how many elements have been created (notice that you don't want to decrement to track all created objects, because then you may create two elements with the same name).

I don't think you can pass the name you want into the new function, but you can always set the name after creating it.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like your looking for a `List<TextBox>`.

Comment: ok then later on can we treat it like real text box like all its properties events etc etc

Comment: @Afnan: It _is_ a real textbox.

Comment: @Drach: The `Name` doesn't matter.

Comment: yes i hope so actully i have to read a text file and generate check boxes depending on number of rows in file

Comment: Like when ever we call the control we do it by its name.

Comment: But I didn't think you could set two elements with the same name, even if they were dynamic. Granted, I don't think it will, so I'm not entirely sure what the problem is from Afnan (I think we need real code that "doesn't work"). But if he wants to enumerate each of them ~~ About here my brain says "so what if he needs to iter over them" because that code goes like this: `foreach ( TextBox txtBox in Form.Controls)` ... duh