# Iterating controls on button click in c# windows application

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I am trying to create a windows application where I want to display a group of controls (Combo Box, Text Box and a button) on button click inside a panel.

I have created a code to create controls once but I want to create them again and again on button click one below another.

The code I am using is

```
public partial class Employee_PayHeads_add : Form
{


private TextBox txtBox = new TextBox();
private Button btnAdd = new Button();
private ComboBox combohead = new ComboBox();



public Employee_PayHeads_add()
{
InitializeComponent();
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
this.btnAdd.BackColor = Color.Gray;
this.btnAdd.Text = "Remove";
this.btnAdd.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(240, 25);
this.btnAdd.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(70, 25);


this.txtBox.Text = "";
this.txtBox.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(150, 25);
this.txtBox.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(70, 40);

this.combohead.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(10, 25);

panel1.Controls.Add(btnAdd);
panel1.Controls.Add(txtBox);
panel1.Controls.Add(combohead);


}
```

Also I want a vertical scroller in the panel if number controls overlap the space.

Thanks in advance

Comment: shouldn't your button have an event attacthed?

Comment: Why do you want to recreate your objects? Isn't it more simple to just hide/show the controls?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside the button click event create new objects, instead of using the one you declared before.

Try something like that:

```
public partial class Employee_PayHeads_add : Form
{
    private TextBox txtBox = new TextBox();
    private Button btnAdd = new Button();
    private ComboBox combohead = new ComboBox();

    private int txtBoxStartPosition = 150;
    private int btnAddStartPosition = 240;
    private int comboheadStartPosition = 10;
}

public Employee_PayHeads_add()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TextBox newTxtBox = new TextBox();
    Button newBtnAdd = new Button();
    ComboBox newCombohead = new ComboBox();

    newBtnAdd.BackColor = Color.Gray;
    newBtnAdd.Text = "Remove";
    newBtnAdd.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(btnAddStartPosition, 25);
    newBtnAdd.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(70, 25);

    newTxtBox.Text = "";
    newTxtBox.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(txtBoxStartPosition, 25);
    newTxtBox.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(70, 40);

    newCombohead.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(comboheadStartPosition, 25);

    panel1.Controls.Add(newBtnAdd);
    panel1.Controls.Add(newTxtBox);
    panel1.Controls.Add(newCombohead);

    txtBoxStartPosition += 50;
    btnAddStartPosition += 50;
    comboheadStartPosition += 50;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! It worked, is there any way to get a scroller in the panel to see the hidden controls?

Comment: Glad to hear it worked! To get a scroller try use [AutoScroll property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.scrollablecontrol.autoscroll%28v=vs.100%29.aspx): add to your code `panel1.Controls.AutoScroll = true;`

Comment: How can we handle the events of these dynamically created controls individually?

Comment: I think you need to work with something like `newBtnAdd.Click += new EventHandler(NewBtnHandler /*new method where you make button operations*/);`, but I'm not shure about this. I suggest to take a look to [this MSDN discussion](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/csharpgeneral/thread/e3ff0e36-40b8-430a-98da-25e44570cd08/) and to [this StackOverflow question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1434282/how-do-i-create-5-buttons-and-assign-individual-click-events-dynamically/1434422#1434422). Hope it'll put you on the correct way.

Comment: Thanks Spaceman!
This thing I have done already but trying to fire the event of every control individually. Thanks for your support

Answer (score 0):

I havent tried your code yet, but it shows that it is always creating the new controls on every click event, but as youo have specified the hardcoaded location for buttons, so it must be creating new controls overlapping each other. so you can change the location dynamically and hopefully it will work

Answer (score -1):

If you want to add the controls again and again you have to create new ones. So rather than defining them in your form like that you have to:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   Button btnAdd = new Button();
   btnAdd.BackColor = Color.Gray;
   btnAdd.Text = "Remove";
   btnAdd.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(240, 25);
   btnAdd.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(70, 25);

   TextBox txtBox = new TextBox();
   txtBox.Text = "";
   txtBox.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(150, 25);
   txtBox.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(70, 40);

   ComboBox combohead = new ComboBox();
   combohead.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(10, 25);

   panel1.Controls.Add(btnAdd);
   panel1.Controls.Add(txtBox);
   panel1.Controls.Add(combohead);
}
```

Now you can remove those private declarations on top of your class.

Comment: That wasnt the issue, code clearly shows its overlapping the new controls always

Comment: Thanks for your support!
How can we handle the events of these dynamically created controls individually?

Comment: Well in example; you will bind button click events to one button_click event. Here is one trick; give dynamic ids to buttons you are creating and then you can make a switch in the event handler of click event looking for ids and doing proper things.