# How might you add user controls to a window dynamically

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have a program I'm taking from Code Behind and converting to MVVM.  The program is very simple.  It takes text from text boxes and converts the strings into a pipe delaminated text file.  My program has a MainViewWindow and 3 User Controls that use a ModernUI tab system to determine which User Control populates the MainViewWindow.  I'm only working on the first User Control for now.  I'm using a SimpleIoc (ViewModelLocator) to identify which User Control is selected and "active" on the MainViewWindow.  The User Control has ~30 text boxes that are bound to the ViewModel.  Some of these text boxes have buttons that (are supposed to) activate a pop up window that asks for additional information.  For example, the 'Name:' text box has a button next to it that should pop up a window that asks for the First Name, Last Name, Middle Name, Suffix and Prefix all in separate text boxes.  This information is parsed into a single string and separated via '^' symbol and placed back into the 'Name:' text box.  That won't be hard but I want to provide the meat and potatoes.

My problem is I have about 8 places where I need a button to pop up the 'additional information' window.  All of these have different information needed so I have created User Controls with the required fields.  I'm trying to dynamically add to this pop up window when the button is pushed.  I don't know how to pop up a window and add a User Control to a Window via commanding essentially.  This is my logic based off research and conformity with the MVVM framework.  If I am on the right path (which I sure hope!) can someone fill in the gaps?  If there is a better way, point me in the right direction please?

Comment: You can do this with a WPF popup and a template selector, both of which are MVVM compliant.

Comment: @GarryVass So the popup would be declared in the XAML for every button needing this feature? –

Comment: @WillTheThrill, no you've got it backwards, the popup is declared once.  Content for the popup is expressed in templates, and the selector chooses them dynamically.

Comment: @GarryVass Good to go.  I'll do some research on that but on first search, it looks promising.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: @WillTheThrill, it's the right way to go.  If you think a small piece of *indicative* xaml in an answer is of any use, let me know.  But overall, you're on the right track now.  Rachel just posted something which uses a layered strategy and it's fine also.

Comment: @GarryVass Thanks again, lots to look at.  I see long hours in my near future.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, you will need to create a new form and then call it from the button.

Once this form comes up, you dynamically add controls to it that are appropriate for that button.

here is button code to show the additional form:

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            PopupForm form = new PopupForm();
            form.ShowDialog();
        }
```

I won't provide the whole code for you but to dynamically create a control and actually use it, you will need the following info

```
Control type 
Control location 
Control size 
Control name
```

Once the form loads up, it should call some method that will build the controls. This question has been answered before here: [How do I create 5 buttons and assign individual click events dynamically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1434282/how-do-i-create-5-buttons-and-assign-individual-click-events-dynamically/1434422#1434422)

Comment: Sorry, I'm using WPF (not WinForms) and the MVVM framework.  Avoiding events replaced with commanding.

Answer (score 0):

I personally don't like WPF's default PopupControl for a number of reasons, so [have created my own](http://rachel53461.wordpress.com/2011/08/20/popup-panel-for-wpf/) which I think goes better with the MVVM pattern

Even if you create your own, the basic idea is the same. You place your custom PopupControl on top of your View in a control that allows objects to overlap, such as a Grid, like this

```
<Grid>
    <local:MyView />
    <local:MyPopupControl />
</Grid>
```

And you hook up a few bindings on the popup control

```
<Grid x:Name="ParentPanel">
    <local:MyView />
    <local:MyPopupControl 
        Content="{Binding PopupContent}"
        local:MyPopupControl.PopupParent="{Binding ElementName=ParentPanel}"
        local:MyPopupControl.IsPopupVisible="{Binding IsPopupVisible}"/>
</Grid>
```

Then from your ViewModel you just set the appropriate properties to have it appear

```
PopupContent = new AddressViewModel();
IsPopupVisible = true;
```

Then magic occurs causing the Popup to appear overtop of your main view, with it's content property set to your new ViewModel, drawn using a DataTemplate of your definition, and all is good and right in the world once again.

But in all seriousness, here's the code I use for my custom PopupControl, in case my blog link ever stops working. I'd still recommend you read it for an example though.

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Animation;
using System.Windows.Threading;

namespace PopupPanelSample
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Panel for handling Popups:
    /// - Control with name PART_DefaultFocusControl will have default focus
    /// - Can define PopupParent to determine if this popup should be hosted in a parent panel or not
    /// - Can define the property EnterKeyCommand to specifify what command to run when the Enter key is pressed
    /// - Can define the property EscapeKeyCommand to specify what command to run when the Escape key is pressed
    /// - Can define BackgroundOpacity to specify how opaque the background will be. Value is between 0 and 1.
    /// </summary>
    public partial class PopupPanel : UserControl
    {
        #region Fields

        bool _isLoading = false;                    // Flag to tell identify when DataContext changes
        private UIElement _lastFocusControl;        // Last control that had focus when popup visibility changes, but isn't closed

        #endregion // Fields

        #region Constructors

        public PopupPanel()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.DataContextChanged += Popup_DataContextChanged;

            // Register a PropertyChanged event on IsPopupVisible
            DependencyPropertyDescriptor dpd = DependencyPropertyDescriptor.FromProperty(PopupPanel.IsPopupVisibleProperty, typeof(PopupPanel));
            if (dpd != null) dpd.AddValueChanged(this, delegate { IsPopupVisible_Changed(); });

            dpd = DependencyPropertyDescriptor.FromProperty(PopupPanel.ContentProperty, typeof(PopupPanel));
            if (dpd != null) dpd.AddValueChanged(this, delegate { Content_Changed(); });

        }

        #endregion // Constructors

        #region Events

        #region Property Change Events

        // When DataContext changes
        private void Popup_DataContextChanged(object sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            DisableAnimationWhileLoading();
        }

        // When Content Property changes
        private void Content_Changed()
        {
            DisableAnimationWhileLoading();
        }

        // Sets an IsLoading flag so storyboard doesn't run while loading
        private void DisableAnimationWhileLoading()
        {
            _isLoading = true;
            this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Render,
                new Action(delegate() { _isLoading = false; }));
        }

        // Run storyboard when IsPopupVisible property changes to true
        private void IsPopupVisible_Changed()
        {
            bool isShown = GetIsPopupVisible(this);

            if (isShown && !_isLoading)
            {
                FrameworkElement panel = FindChild<FrameworkElement>(this, "PopupPanelContent");
                if (panel != null)
                {
                    // Run Storyboard
                    Storyboard animation = (Storyboard)panel.FindResource("ShowEditPanelStoryboard");
                    animation.Begin();
                }
            }

            // When hiding popup, clear the LastFocusControl
            if (!isShown)
            {
                _lastFocusControl = null;
            }
        }

        #endregion // Change Events

        #region Popup Events

        // When visibility is changed, set the default focus
        void PopupPanel_IsVisibleChanged(object sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if ((bool)e.NewValue)
            {
                ContentControl popupControl = FindChild<ContentControl>(this, "PopupContentControl");
                this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Render,
                    new Action(delegate()
                    {
                        // Verify object really is visible because sometimes it's not once we switch to Render
                        if (!GetIsPopupVisible(this))
                        {
                            return;
                        }

                        if (_lastFocusControl != null && _lastFocusControl.Focusable)
                        {
                            _lastFocusControl.Focus();
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            _lastFocusControl = FindChild<UIElement>(popupControl, "PART_DefaultFocusControl") as UIElement;

                            // If we can find the part named PART_DefaultFocusControl, set focus to it
                            if (_lastFocusControl != null && _lastFocusControl.Focusable)
                            {
                                _lastFocusControl.Focus();
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                _lastFocusControl = FindFirstFocusableChild(popupControl);

                                // If no DefaultFocusControl found, try and set focus to the first focusable element found in popup
                                if (_lastFocusControl != null)
                                {
                                    _lastFocusControl.Focus();
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    // Just give the Popup UserControl focus so it can handle keyboard input
                                    popupControl.Focus();
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    )
                );
            }
        }

        // When popup loses focus but isn't hidden, store the last element that had focus so we can put it back later
        void PopupPanel_LostFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            DependencyObject focusScope = FocusManager.GetFocusScope(this);
            _lastFocusControl = FocusManager.GetFocusedElement(focusScope) as UIElement;
        }

        // Keyboard Events
        private void PopupPanel_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Key == Key.Escape)
            {
                PopupPanel popup = FindAncester<PopupPanel>((DependencyObject)sender);
                ICommand cmd = GetPopupEscapeKeyCommand(popup);
                if (cmd != null && cmd.CanExecute(null))
                {
                    cmd.Execute(null);
                    e.Handled = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    // By default the Escape Key closes the popup when pressed
                    var expression = this.GetBindingExpression(PopupPanel.IsPopupVisibleProperty);
                    var dataType = expression.DataItem.GetType();
                    dataType.GetProperties().Single(x => x.Name == expression.ParentBinding.Path.Path)
                        .SetValue(expression.DataItem, false, null);
                }
            }
            else if (e.Key == Key.Enter)
            {
                // Don't want to run Enter command if focus is in a TextBox with AcceptsReturn = True
                if (!(e.KeyboardDevice.FocusedElement is TextBox &&
                     (e.KeyboardDevice.FocusedElement as TextBox).AcceptsReturn == true))
                {
                    PopupPanel popup = FindAncester<PopupPanel>((DependencyObject)sender);
                    ICommand cmd = GetPopupEnterKeyCommand(popup);
                    if (cmd != null && cmd.CanExecute(null))
                    {
                        cmd.Execute(null);
                        e.Handled = true;
                    }
                }

            }
        }

        #endregion // Popup Events

        #endregion // Events

        #region Dependency Properties

        // Parent for Popup
        #region PopupParent

        public static readonly DependencyProperty PopupParentProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("PopupParent", typeof(FrameworkElement),
            typeof(PopupPanel), new PropertyMetadata(null, null, CoercePopupParent));

        private static object CoercePopupParent(DependencyObject obj, object value)
        {
            // If PopupParent is null, return the Window object
            return (value ?? FindAncester<Window>(obj));
        }

        public FrameworkElement PopupParent
        {
            get { return (FrameworkElement)this.GetValue(PopupParentProperty); }
            set { this.SetValue(PopupParentProperty, value); }
        }

        // Providing Get/Set methods makes them show up in the XAML designer
        public static FrameworkElement GetPopupParent(DependencyObject obj)
        {
            return (FrameworkElement)obj.GetValue(PopupParentProperty);
        }

        public static void SetPopupParent(DependencyObject obj, FrameworkElement value)
        {
            obj.SetValue(PopupParentProperty, value);
        }

        #endregion

        // Popup Visibility - If popup is shown or not
        #region IsPopupVisibleProperty

        public static readonly DependencyProperty IsPopupVisibleProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("IsPopupVisible", typeof(bool),
            typeof(PopupPanel), new PropertyMetadata(false, null));

        public static bool GetIsPopupVisible(DependencyObject obj)
        {
            return (bool)obj.GetValue(IsPopupVisibleProperty);
        }

        public static void SetIsPopupVisible(DependencyObject obj, bool value)
        {
            obj.SetValue(IsPopupVisibleProperty, value);
        }

        #endregion // IsPopupVisibleProperty

        // Transparency level for the background filler outside the popup
        #region BackgroundOpacityProperty

        public static readonly DependencyProperty BackgroundOpacityProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("BackgroundOpacity", typeof(double),
            typeof(PopupPanel), new PropertyMetadata(.5, null));

        public static double GetBackgroundOpacity(DependencyObject obj)
        {
            return (double)obj.GetValue(BackgroundOpacityProperty);
        }

        public static void SetBackgroundOpacity(DependencyObject obj, double value)
        {
            obj.SetValue(BackgroundOpacityProperty, value);
        }

        #endregion ShowBackgroundProperty

        // Command to execute when Enter key is pressed
        #region PopupEnterKeyCommandProperty

        public static readonly DependencyProperty PopupEnterKeyCommandProperty =
            DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("PopupEnterKeyCommand", typeof(ICommand),
            typeof(PopupPanel), new PropertyMetadata(null, null));

        public static ICommand GetPopupEnterKeyCommand(DependencyObject obj)
        {
            return (ICommand)obj.GetValue(PopupEnterKeyCommandProperty);
        }

        public static void SetPopupEnterKeyCommand(DependencyObject obj, ICommand value)
        {
            obj.SetValue(PopupEnterKeyCommandProperty, value);
        }

        #endregion PopupEnterKeyCommandProperty

        // Command to execute when Enter key is pressed
        #region PopupEscapeKeyCommandProperty

        public static readonly DependencyProperty PopupEscapeKeyCommandProperty =
            DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("PopupEscapeKeyCommand", typeof(ICommand),
            typeof(PopupPanel), new PropertyMetadata(null, null));

        public static ICommand GetPopupEscapeKeyCommand(DependencyObject obj)
        {
            return (ICommand)obj.GetValue(PopupEscapeKeyCommandProperty);
        }

        public static void SetPopupEscapeKeyCommand(DependencyObject obj, ICommand value)
        {
            obj.SetValue(PopupEscapeKeyCommandProperty, value);
        }

        #endregion PopupEscapeKeyCommandProperty

        #endregion Dependency Properties

        #region Visual Tree Helpers

        public static UIElement FindFirstFocusableChild(DependencyObject parent)
        {
            // Confirm parent is valid.
            if (parent == null) return null;

            UIElement foundChild = null;

            int childrenCount = VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(parent);
            for (int i = 0; i < childrenCount; i++)
            {
                UIElement child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(parent, i) as UIElement;

                // This is returning me things like ContentControls, so for now filtering to buttons/textboxes only
                if (child != null && child.Focusable && child.IsVisible)
                {
                    foundChild = child;
                    break;
                }
                // recursively drill down the tree
                foundChild = FindFirstFocusableChild(child);

                // If the child is found, break so we do not overwrite the found child.
                if (foundChild != null) break;
            }
            return foundChild;
        }

        public static T FindAncester<T>(DependencyObject current)
        where T : DependencyObject
        {
            // Need this call to avoid returning current object if it is the same type as parent we are looking for
            current = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(current);

            while (current != null)
            {
                if (current is T)
                {
                    return (T)current;
                }
                current = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(current);
            };
            return null;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Looks for a child control within a parent by name
        /// </summary>
        public static T FindChild<T>(DependencyObject parent, string childName)
        where T : DependencyObject
        {
            // Confirm parent and childName are valid.
            if (parent == null) return null;

            T foundChild = null;

            int childrenCount = VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(parent);
            for (int i = 0; i < childrenCount; i++)
            {
                var child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(parent, i);
                // If the child is not of the request child type child
                T childType = child as T;
                if (childType == null)
                {
                    // recursively drill down the tree
                    foundChild = FindChild<T>(child, childName);

                    // If the child is found, break so we do not overwrite the found child.
                    if (foundChild != null) break;
                }
                else if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(childName))
                {
                    var frameworkElement = child as FrameworkElement;
                    // If the child's name is set for search
                    if (frameworkElement != null && frameworkElement.Name == childName)
                    {
                        // if the child's name is of the request name
                        foundChild = (T)child;
                        break;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        // recursively drill down the tree
                        foundChild = FindChild<T>(child, childName);

                        // If the child is found, break so we do not overwrite the found child.
                        if (foundChild != null) break;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    // child element found.
                    foundChild = (T)child;
                    break;
                }
            }

            return foundChild;
        }

        #endregion

    }

    // Converter for Popup positioning
    public class ValueDividedByParameterConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            double n, d;
            if (double.TryParse(value.ToString(), out n)
                && double.TryParse(parameter.ToString(), out d)
                && d != 0)
            {
                return n / d;
            }

            return 0;
        }        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Makes sense.  Would I be able to use the data template with a dialog that uses the same binding you use in the PopUpControl?  Would that be a better/worse idea?

Comment: Yes, I frequently define implicit DataTemplates inside `<local:MyPopupControl.Resources>` to tell WPF how to render the different objects that could possibly occur in the Popup's Content. I think my blog post even has a link to a sample project for download if you want to play with it a bit before deciding if or how you want to implement your own version :)

Comment: Thanks!  Much to research and now the fun begins.