# ViewModel with parameters

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a little problem. I have a form in WPF, which is for high employee. I also use the same form for editing employees. In .xaml.cs form file, I have two constructors. One is for when I want to register and the other for when I want to edit.

```
private readonly EmpleadoViewModel _empleadoVm;

public AltaModificacionEmpleado()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    _empleadoVm = (EmpleadoViewModel) DataContext;
    _empleadoVm.ModoAlta = true;
    _empleadoVm.TituloVentana = "Alta de empleado";
    _empleadoVm.Empleado = new Empleado();
}

public AltaModificacionEmpleado(Empleado empleadoSeleccionado)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    _empleadoVm = (EmpleadoViewModel) DataContext;
    _empleadoVm.Empleado = empleadoSeleccionado;
    _empleadoVm.TituloVentana = "Editar empleado";
    _empleadoVm.IsVisible = Visibility.Collapsed;
    _empleadoVm.Cerrar = Close;
}
```

I need to pass some parameters when creating the DataContext, because between "DC" creation and the first property, XAML is responsible for certain things that have to control with these parameters I need to pass. Thanks!

**EDIT**

I have 2 ViewModel. 1 to register employees (AltaModificacionEmpleado) and another to search employees (BuscarEmpleadoViewModel).

There are two buttons, one that opens the form to register employees, and the other opens a form with ListView + button to search for employees. When I find the one I want, double click and employee registration form opens, but now with the loaded data, to modify (Binding).

**for ex: in AltaModificacionEmpleado.xaml**

```
<ListView ... ...
SelectedItem="{Binding EmpleadoSeleccionado}"
..
../>
```

**for ex: In BuscarEmpleadoViewModel**

```
private void Editar()
{
    try
    {
        var frm = new AltaModificacionEmpleado(EmpleadoSeleccionado);
        frm.ShowDialog();
    }
    catch (Exception dbEx)
    {
        ...
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you're trying to do too much with the view. Rather than having one view that takes parameters, what if you created two views. Each view can then maintain exactly what it needs to do with out showing/hiding a bunch of controls. Then each view can use their own ViewModel.  This would follow the [Single Responsibility Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle) and should simplify this whole process.

Comment: If your layers are separated correctly, you should never be passing a business value (Empleado) to a UI object (AltaModificaoionEmpleado) and expecting it to send the object back to the business layer(EmpleadoViewModel). How is your UI object created? What determines if you have an employee object to pass to it or not? It sounds like you should have a parent ViewModel controlling your business layer, and your UI layer should be written so it just displays your business objects in a user-friendly manner.

Comment: @avechuche What you should have is `BuscarEmpleadoViewModel` doing something like `this.Employee = new EmpleadoViewModel(EmpleadoSeleccionado)`, and have your View bind something like a ContentControl.Content to `BuscarEmpleadoViewModel.Employee`. Since it looks like you want a popup, I would personally use something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23351266/302677), although if a popup is not required its much easier to just use a ContentControl on your screen with something like [this](https://rachel53461.wordpress.com/2011/05/28/switching-between-viewsusercontrols-using-mvvm/)