# Add buttons by code to my form

Tags: c#, winforms, button

I need to create x number of buttons by code and place them into a groupBox when I load a form, each one with its own click and right click event (contextMenuStrip)

I've seen other questions about dynamically adding buttons here and they only allow a fixed number of buttons to be created but for me that number varies everytime I open the form.

If it is not possible please suggest me another way to do this.

Comment: Use those other answers and a `for` loop...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1434282/how-do-i-create-5-buttons-and-assign-individual-click-events-dynamically

Comment: @loli in that case its 5 buttons and for the click event a switch is needed from 0 to 4 but for me i dont know how many buttons i will need to create

Comment: @IsaacTuncarCedron You can't create an _unknown_ number of buttons, right? You don't have to hardcode the exact amount of course, you could also have the number in a variable, and use that variable in a for loop. Or instead of a numeric variable, have a list of button names from which you generate them.

Comment: The real problem here is what you want to do when the user click your buttons. If every button need to perform a different task then you need some kind of key associated to your buttons when you create them and the use that key to determine what to do when the user clicks the button. Could you explain what you want to do in the click event of every button?

Comment: @Steve The buttons will open a form but with diferent values for the textboxes, labels, etc. These values depend on  what button was clicked.

Comment: @C. Evenhuis I dont have the control of the number of buttons to be created because that comes from a database.My worry is how would I handle events for lets says 20 buttons or maybe 30 buttons because i dont know how many buttons will be created

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this example (run it on LinqPAD) I use a FlowLayout container to automatically put the buttons on your form surface and for every button created I define a custom action that should be performed when your button is pressed

```
void Main()
{
    Form f = new Form();
    FlowLayoutPanel fp = new FlowLayoutPanel();
    fp.FlowDirection = FlowDirection.LeftToRight;
    fp.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
    f.Controls.Add(fp);

    // Get the number of buttons needed and create them in a loop    
    int numOfButtons = GetNumOfButtons();
    for (int x = 0; x < numOfButtons; x++)
    {
        Button b = new Button();
        // Define what action should be performed by the button X
        b.Tag = GetAction(x);
        b.Text = "BTN:" + x.ToString("D2");
        b.Click += onClick;
        fp.Controls.Add(b);
    }
    f.ShowDialog();
}

// Every button will call this event handler, but then you look at the 
// Tag property to decide which code to execute
void onClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Button b = sender as Button;
    int x = Convert.ToInt32(b.Text.Split(':')[1]);
    Action<int, string> act = b.Tag as Action<int, string>;
    act.Invoke(x, b.Text);

}

// This stub creates the action for the button at index X
// You should change it to satisfy your requirements 
Action<int, string> GetAction(int x)
{
    return (int i, string s) => Console.WriteLine("Button " + i.ToString() + " clicked with text=" + s);
}

// Another stub that you need to define the number of buttons needed
int GetNumOfButtons()
{ 
    return 20;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, you gave me some ideas.

Answer (score 1):

It's vb.net example but You can easy convert using some online converting tool.

```
Dim lp As Integer = 0, tp As Integer = 0  'lp-left position, tp-top position in Your groupBox
For x = 1 to 20
 Dim btn As New Button
 btn.Name = "btn" + x.ToString
 btn.Text = x.ToString
 btn.Left = lp
 btn.Top = tp
 btn.Size = New Size(30, 30)
 AddHandler btn.Click, AddressOf btnClick
 groupBox.Controls.Add(btn)
 tp += btn.Height + 10
Next

Private Sub btnClick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
 Dim btn As Button = DirectCast(sender, Button)
 'for example
 If btn.Name = "btn1" Then
  'do something if You click on first button, ...
 End If
End Sub
```

This is basic example how to dynamically create 20 buttons and place them into groupbox... so You can do with position and size of button what You need. With `AddHandler` You can define right click and so on... You'll see what's offered.

In this example, button will be placed one under other, and so on. Button text will be numbers. Put this code in `Form_Load`.

And, when You open Your form under `Form1_Load` You can define how many button You need.

Comment: Answers provided are supposed to be working and in the language of the question.

Comment: @deathismyfriend Why should they? You help people more by explaining how to solve the problem instead of providing a copy paste ready answer.

Comment: @deathismyfriend Well, provided answer working...  And about prog.language... You are right and wrong... in many cases I got anwsers in `c#` instead `vb.net` (but tag was `vb.net`) and I never make some problems about that. Big deal. But it's Your opinion. Like C.Evenhuis wrote. It will be nice if You point which part not working. Everybody made mistakes.

Comment: @C.Evenhuis It's now my opinion about what language answers should be in. You should take a look at the rules for this site. They specify that answers given should be in the same language as the question.

Comment: @deathismyfriend Look, arguing with You is wasting time, nothing else... I know about rules... there are flexible peoples and someone's aren't... then by rules I had to downvote approx. 80% of answers for my question... just because they are wrote in `c#` instead `vb.net` ... but all answers helped me finding solutions... cheers.

Comment: @deathismyfriend Where did you find these rules? http://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers doesn't mention language, I don't know where else to look. I agree the same language is _preferable_ over other languages, but I don't see how any attempt to take time to help someone should be "against the rules". If it really is against the rules, you should flag the answer so a moderator can remove it.