# How to add textboxes into windows form when you don't know how many you will need (it will change constantly)

Tags: c#, .net, forms, windows-forms-designer

I have been trying to make a bill for a project and I am stuck, the title defines my problem. I know it is an odd question for this site but I am thankful for anyone that helps me out.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1434282/how-do-i-create-5-buttons-and-assign-individual-click-events-dynamically

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/developer/visualstudio/csharp/language-compilers/add-controls-to-windows-forms